# pygame world generation algorithm

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a game for a school project using pygame and was struggling to make a world generation algorithm I was wondering if anyone could help me. for anyone wondering the game is a rip off version of the game Terreira if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If there is a specific part of the process that you are having trouble with, others can help you. Please refer to this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) for more details on how to pose good questions that relate to assignments.

Answer (score 1):

One way of making a map in pygame is to do it using tiles, but I find that it to be massive effort, since you first have to learn how to use it. Another more common way to do it is to create a 2-D list representing your `x` and `y` for every point in your map, depending on how you scale the map.First lets talk about the map creation:

```
# lets say 0 represents empty space
# 1 represents a block image u might have for example dirt image or a wall

    layout = [ [1, 0, 2],
               [0, 1, 1] ]
```

Then, to actually draw the map you can loop over this list, first every  layer in the list, then every element in that layer, like this:

```
 y = 0
    for layer in layout:
        x = 0
        for element in layer:
           if element == 1:
               D.blit(your image, (x *  block_length, y * block_height))
           if element == 2:
               D.blit(your image, (x *  other_block_length, y * other_block_height)) 
           else: # else do nothing, which  leaves the area empty
               pass
       x += 1 # add 1 to x every inner loop
     y += 1 # add 1 to y value every outer loop
```

Here is an example from one of my games

```
class Game_map:
    def __init__(self):
        self.land = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\pro-gramar\OneDrive\Documents\A level python codes\final game\land.png").convert()
        self.height = 200
        self.width = 200
        self.land = pygame.transform.scale(self.land, (170 , 200))
        self.land.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))

        self.map_width = 6000
        self.map_height = 2000

        # 0 = emepty
        # 1 = land

        self.layout = [[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ,0 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                              [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]]



    def draw(self):
        y = 0
        for layer in self.layout:
            x = 0
            for land in layer:
                if land == 1:
                    D.blit(self.land, (x * 160 ,  y * 200 ))
                if land == 0:
                    pass

                x += 1
            y += 1
```